# Superpowered Sdk- write changed audio effected file to external storage

Tags: android, android-studio, superpowered

I need to write the output file in external storage with applied effects but don't know how to do this. Any help will be highly appreciated to make audio output mp3 or mp4 file with effects. I have successfully done the pitch change of real time, I have used some code of [write file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316295/how-to-write-file-to-external-storage-using-superpowered-sdk-in-android) but the file generated is only 0 bytes and corrupted.I have used below code

```
 const char *output1 = "/storage/emulated/0/Music/123456.mp3";
const char *openError = decoder->open(input, false, 0, 0, 0);
if (openError) {
    delete decoder;
    return false;
};

FILE *fd = createWAV(output1, decoder->samplerate, 2);
if (!fd) {
    delete decoder;
    return false;
};

float effectMix = 0.5f;
SuperpoweredFX *effect = NULL;
if (effectId == 0) {
    player->setPitchShift(10);
    effect = new SuperpoweredEcho(decoder->samplerate);
    ((SuperpoweredEcho *) effect)->setMix(effectMix);
} else if (effectId == 1) {
    effect = new SuperpoweredReverb(decoder->samplerate);
    ((SuperpoweredReverb *) effect)->setMix(effectMix);
}

if (effect == NULL) {
    delete decoder;
    return false;
}

effect->enable(true);
short int *intBuffer = (short int *) malloc(
decoder->samplesPerFrame * 2 * sizeof(short int) + 16384);
float *floatBuffer = (float *) malloc(decoder->samplesPerFrame * 2 * sizeof(float) + 1024);
unsigned int samplesDecoded;
while (true) {
    samplesDecoded = decoder->samplesPerFrame;
    if (decoder->decode(intBuffer, &samplesDecoded) == SUPERPOWEREDDECODER_ERROR) {
        break;
    }
    if (samplesDecoded < 1) {
        break;
    }

    SuperpoweredShortIntToFloat(intBuffer, floatBuffer, samplesDecoded);

    effect->process(floatBuffer, floatBuffer, samplesDecoded);

    // Convert the PCM samples from 32-bit floating point to 16-bit integer.
    SuperpoweredFloatToShortInt(floatBuffer, intBuffer, samplesDecoded);
}


fwrite(intBuffer, 1, samplesDecoded * 4, fd);
closeWAV(fd);
delete decoder;
delete effect;
free(intBuffer);
free(floatBuffer);
return true;
```

Please help with this code.

I have error like below.

```
    11-14 14:48:35.447 10065-10065/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:10065
11-14 14:48:35.497 10065-10070/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-14 14:48:35.507 10065-10070/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-14 14:48:35.537 10065-10065/? I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
11-14 14:48:35.627 10065-10065/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
11-14 14:48:35.647 10065-10065/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
    com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
11-14 14:48:35.647 10065-10065/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
11-14 14:48:35.847 10065-10080/? V/FA: Collection enabled
    App package, google app id: com.korakoepitchchanger, 1:872304933700:android:c6dbb37cfd23f040
11-14 14:48:35.847 10065-10080/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 13001
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.korakoepitchchanger
11-14 14:48:35.847 10065-10080/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
11-14 14:48:35.947 10065-10080/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
11-14 14:48:36.127 10065-10080/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
11-14 14:48:36.497 10065-10065/? V/FA: onActivityCreated
11-14 14:48:36.557 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
11-14 14:48:36.587 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2861861576925568549}]
11-14 14:48:36.657 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity resumed, time: 187857395
11-14 14:48:36.707 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger D/FA: Connected to remote service
11-14 14:48:36.707 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
11-14 14:48:37.077 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 530
    Activity paused, time: 187857925
11-14 14:48:37.217 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: onActivityCreated
11-14 14:48:37.377 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.3.25
11-14 14:48:37.437 10065-10164/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 24(0x73657474696e67),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.korakoepitchchanger
    [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
11-14 14:48:37.457 10065-10164/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
11-14 14:48:37.997 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:10900
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 10900
11-14 14:48:38.097 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000034/n/arm64-v8a
11-14 14:48:38.167 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
    Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
11-14 14:48:38.797 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 70.0.3538.80 (code 353808050)
11-14 14:48:39.077 10065-10164/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 19(0x6170692e637261),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.korakoepitchchanger
11-14 14:48:39.087 10065-10164/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
11-14 14:48:39.107 10065-10164/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
11-14 14:48:39.317 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8353(1299KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 101MB/102MB, paused 1.796ms total 102.918ms
11-14 14:48:39.327 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<hs>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<hs>
11-14 14:48:39.387 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 1635-1637)
11-14 14:48:39.647 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-14 14:48:39.657 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "70.0.3538.80", actual native library version number "70.0.3538.80"
11-14 14:48:39.807 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
11-14 14:48:39.867 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger W/art: Suspending all threads took: 54.598ms
11-14 14:48:39.877 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10288(811KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 101MB/102MB, paused 57.343ms total 82.106ms
11-14 14:48:40.657 10065-10164/com.korakoepitchchanger W/CrashlyticsCore: Expected method missing: registerOnMeasurementEventListener
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:616)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:586)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.u.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.u.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.l.d(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.l.f(Unknown Source)
        at b.a.a.a.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at b.a.a.a.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at b.a.a.a.a.c.a$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 14:48:41.177 10065-10317/com.korakoepitchchanger W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
11-14 14:48:41.207 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-14 14:48:41.207 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 8249e7b, Iacb76f3f7d
    Build Date                       : 03/22/16
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1.06.00.01.179.016
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
11-14 14:48:41.427 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
11-14 14:48:41.437 10065-10313/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 27(0x676f6f676c6561),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.korakoepitchchanger
    [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
11-14 14:48:41.457 10065-10313/com.korakoepitchchanger D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
11-14 14:48:41.497 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
11-14 14:48:41.577 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
11-14 14:48:41.597 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
11-14 14:48:41.607 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
    Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
11-14 14:48:41.607 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
11-14 14:48:41.617 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
11-14 14:48:41.637 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
11-14 14:48:41.677 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.034ms
11-14 14:48:41.687 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3313(196KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 102MB/102MB, paused 12.936ms total 70.241ms
11-14 14:48:41.747 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.534ms
11-14 14:48:41.757 10065-10075/com.korakoepitchchanger I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12066(895KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(120KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 102MB/118MB, paused 11.969ms total 73.844ms
11-14 14:48:41.777 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14574021.12451000.1
    Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("8884694ABCF6A031A5CA1B31EF06F481") to get test ads on this device.
11-14 14:48:41.777 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
11-14 14:48:41.797 10065-10337/com.korakoepitchchanger I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
11-14 14:48:41.957 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger D/FA: Logging event (FE): _vs, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2861861576925568549, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2861861576925568551}]
11-14 14:48:42.047 10065-10236/com.korakoepitchchanger W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
11-14 14:48:42.067 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 187862712
11-14 14:48:42.847 10065-10077/com.korakoepitchchanger W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-14 14:48:42.877 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2861861576925568551, ad_event_id(_aeid)=2861861576925568550}]
11-14 14:48:42.927 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
11-14 14:48:43.237 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger E/=>>>: Visible
11-14 14:48:47.897 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Activity paused, time: 187868740
11-14 14:48:47.897 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=6028, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2861861576925568551}]
11-14 14:48:51.817 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 187872663
    Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 7
11-14 14:48:51.827 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Activity paused, time: 187872669
11-14 14:48:52.017 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: onActivityCreated
11-14 14:48:52.087 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/>>>: applied
11-14 14:48:52.097 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/>>>: applied
11-14 14:48:52.097 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger E/>>>: /storage/emulated/0/Music/123.mp3
11-14 14:48:52.187 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/>>>: applied
11-14 14:48:52.207 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger E/>>>>: 30
11-14 14:48:52.257 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2861861576925568551, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Temp2Activity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2861861576925568552}]
11-14 14:48:52.377 10065-10080/com.korakoepitchchanger V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 187873057
11-14 14:48:53.137 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Music/123.mp3
11-14 14:48:53.137 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger V/MediaPlayer: network type=wifi
11-14 14:48:53.167 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger I/MediaPlayer: It's not a proxy project.
11-14 14:48:53.167 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger D/MediaPlayer: ANDROID_HTC_INVOKE_GET_CALLING_PROCESS packageName: com.korakoepitchchanger
11-14 14:48:53.247 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
11-14 14:48:53.307 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger E/>>>>: 30
11-14 14:48:54.307 10065-10065/com.korakoepitchchanger E/>>>>: 30
11-14 14:48:54.577 10065-10761/com.korakoepitchchanger A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x5570b17e30 passed to dlfree
11-14 14:48:54.777 10065-10761/com.korakoepitchchanger W/google-breakpad: Failed to generate minidump.
11-14 14:48:54.877 10065-10761/com.korakoepitchchanger W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
    Chrome build fingerprint:
    70.0.3538.80
    353808050
    ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-14 14:48:54.877 10065-10761/com.korakoepitchchanger A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 10761 (AsyncTask #1)
11-14 14:48:56.687 10065-10759/com.korakoepitchchanger W/AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0x5570bad4f0 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
```

Comment: what is your completed error log cat?

Comment: @Ninja see my edited question for full logcat.

Comment: @Gabor Szanto  How to pitch shift in this code ? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error log shows some firebase issues but one major issue found in the code is you have put

```
fwrite(intBuffer, 1, samplesDecoded * 4, fd);
```

outside the while loop.

It should be inside it as the intBuffer gets filled with chunk of audio data in each iteration.